# Is it possible to alternate mice with a Java Swing program?

Tags: java, swing

Happy New Year Programmers!

Imagine a two player Java Swing game running on a computer with two mice.
Is it possible to allocate one mouse per player and lock out each
mouse in turn then swap the active mouse over?
Both mice would share the same MouseListener methods.

I can see no internet reference to such possibilities but I feel that
this situation has been visited before.

georgeFK

Comment: I believe this is impossible. There is only one cursor. Java cannot distinguish which hardware mouse is controlling the cursor.

Comment: Both mice control MouseEventDemo. So in a limited way it works.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the device handling at the underlying OS layer. Most systems merge the inputs into a single virtual mouse, which is why you can have a trackpad and a USB mouse active at the same time. Of course when you try to use both it leads to conflicts in the pointer movement.

I think the way you would implement this would be through a native method that would talk directly to one specific mouse device. So you would use two of these objects to poll each of the mice and control the on screen game controls.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible but of course not in pure Java and thus you would have to use some [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

Check out [ManyMouse](http://icculus.org/manymouse/).

> ManyMouse is a library that abstracts the handling of multiple mice
>   input into a tiny, cross-platform API. It is meant to be used with
>   games and non-traditional applications with unique input needs. On
>   most platforms, it can at least make all USB mice available, but in
>   many cases can make serial mice and built-in laptop trackpads
>   available too.

Here is the source code and everything as its not available on actual website for some or other reason:

- http://hg.icculus.org/icculus/manymouse/file/b9b3d0efe3c8/
- http://hg.icculus.org/icculus/manymouse/file/b9b3d0efe3c8/contrib/java (the java stuff)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. The whole [MSDN Mouse Input manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has no mention for controlling which mouse the signal comes from.

Surely, there are BIOS commands for it, but thus your code will work only for specific computers.

So, if you want a universal solution, you should write your own "double mouse drivers". Or look for such on the net.